# Is there any way to add details or change the error code in AWS HTTP api gateway authorizer?

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, aws-lambda

I'm using HTTP api gateway with custom Lambda authorizer.(verifying FB idtoken)

Most is working well... but I want to add details in authorizer.

Even in case of 'Expired token' or 'Email not verified'

Is there any way to add the details in error message? Now I can only see '{message: Forbidden}'.